# Crash when using CompanionDeviceManager

Tags: android, android-context

I'm trying to use CompanionDeviceManager as per the guide used [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/companion/CompanionDeviceManager).

When attempting to call associate on the instance though I'm getting the following exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.ContextImpl cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
```

I'm obtaining the instance of CompanionDeviceManager in an activity, via `getSystemService(CompanionDeviceManager.class)`, I have tried moving this around, even to onCreate, but there was no change, always the same exception. I've even tried reinstalling the app a few times, with no success. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

In my case I experienced the same error and found out it was because I was changing the context in attachBaseContext (for purposes of dynamically changing the language). I was using:

```
super.attachBaseContext(newBase.createConfigurationContext(config))
```

It seems like CompanionDeviceManager requires the context that creates it to be an Activity (possibly because it is creating a dialog).

I would double check your code using an activity that is a direct descendant of AppCompatActivity, and then it should work. You can then try and find anything that might be changing the context to something other than the activity itself.

If you need to change the language, use something like this:

```
override fun attachBaseContext(newBase: Context) {
        val res = newBase.resources
        val config = res.configuration
        val languageSetting = instance.getLocale(newBase) //get the locale you want from preferences etc.

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17) {
            val locale = if (languageSetting == "")
                Locale.getDefault()
            else
                Locale(languageSetting)
            config.setLocale(locale)

            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 24) {
                //Using createNewConfigurationContext will cause CompanionDeviceManager to crash
                applyOverrideConfiguration(config)
                super.attachBaseContext(newBase)
            }else {
                super.attachBaseContext(newBase.createConfigurationContext(config))
            }
        } else {
            super.attachBaseContext(newBase)
        }
    }
```

Comment: you were right, that was indeed the case, however I need to perform language changes and therefore attach new context, how can I get around it?

Comment: I just updated the answer to include the workaround I'm using.